# Keras: dimension mismatch between input and output after UpSampling2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement RDN from here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08797.pdf

As an input I specify: (64, 64, 3) and I expect on the output (128, 128, 3), but after compiling the model keras says those dimensions do not match and both tensors must be (64, 64, 3), what do?

How code looks like:

```
lr = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3)) # low res

... bunch of residual blocks here, assigned to model var ...

model = Conv2D(12, 4, padding='same')(model)
# Shape at this point is (None, 64, 64, 12)
model = UpSampling2D(size=2)(model)
sr = Conv2D(3, 4, padding='same')(model) # super res
final = Model(lr, sr)
final.compile(Adam(), loss='mse')
```

After I call train_on_batch on final I get:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 128 and 64 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_10/sr/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [32,128,128,3], [32,64,64,3].
```

Here is the model summary:

```
Model: "model_10"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_14 (InputLayer)           [(None, 64, 64, 3)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_183 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   3136        input_14[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_184 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   32800       conv2d_183[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_185 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   16416       conv2d_184[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_106 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_185[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_197 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_184[0][0]                 
                                                                 activation_106[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_186 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   32800       concatenate_197[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_107 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_186[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_198 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_184[0][0]                 
                                                                 activation_107[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_199 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           concatenate_197[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_198[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_187 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   65568       concatenate_199[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_108 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_187[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_200 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_184[0][0]                 
                                                                 activation_108[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_201 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           concatenate_197[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_200[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_202 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           concatenate_199[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_201[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_188 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   8224        concatenate_202[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_41 (Add)                    (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_184[0][0]                 
                                                                 conv2d_188[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_189 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   16416       add_41[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_109 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_189[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_203 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           add_41[0][0]                     
                                                                 activation_109[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_190 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   32800       concatenate_203[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_110 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_190[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_204 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           add_41[0][0]                     
                                                                 activation_110[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_205 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           concatenate_203[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_204[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_191 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   65568       concatenate_205[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_111 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_191[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_206 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           add_41[0][0]                     
                                                                 activation_111[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_207 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           concatenate_203[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_206[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_208 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           concatenate_205[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_207[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_192 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   8224        concatenate_208[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_42 (Add)                    (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           add_41[0][0]                     
                                                                 conv2d_192[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_193 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   16416       add_42[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_112 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_193[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_209 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           add_42[0][0]                     
                                                                 activation_112[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_194 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   32800       concatenate_209[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_113 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_194[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_210 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           add_42[0][0]                     
                                                                 activation_113[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_211 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           concatenate_209[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_210[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_195 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   65568       concatenate_211[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_114 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_195[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_212 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           add_42[0][0]                     
                                                                 activation_114[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_213 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 128)  0           concatenate_209[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_212[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_214 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 256)  0           concatenate_211[0][0]            
                                                                 concatenate_213[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_196 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   8224        concatenate_214[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_43 (Add)                    (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           add_42[0][0]                     
                                                                 conv2d_196[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_215 (Concatenate)   (None, 64, 64, 96)   0           add_41[0][0]                     
                                                                 add_42[0][0]                     
                                                                 add_43[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_197 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   6208        concatenate_215[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_198 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   65600       conv2d_197[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_44 (Add)                    (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_198[0][0]                 
                                                                 conv2d_183[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_199 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 64)   65600       add_44[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_115 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 64)   0           conv2d_199[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_200 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 32)   32800       activation_115[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_116 (Activation)     (None, 64, 64, 32)   0           conv2d_200[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_201 (Conv2D)             (None, 64, 64, 12)   6156        activation_116[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_3 (UpSampling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 12) 0           conv2d_201[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sr (Conv2D)                     (None, 128, 128, 3)  579         up_sampling2d_3[0][0]            
==================================================================================================
Total params: 581,903
Trainable params: 581,903
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Are you sure the output of model should have the shape `(None, 128, 28, 3)`? what is the shape of your labels?

Comment: I think the problem might be in the shape of the images, are you sure they are of shape `(64, 64, 3)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the error message again:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 128 and 64 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model_10/sr/BiasAdd, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [32,128,128,3], [32,64,64,3].
```

We'll realize that it's not saying that the input and output shape of your model must be same, but it says you are passing incorrect label(target) size to the model loss function (mean_squared_error). **Because the output shape of your model is (128, 128, 3), but you are passing target data with shape (64, 64, 3).** Actually your problem is not in the provided model architecture, but it is in the model.train_on_batch() section that you are passing your data. Maybe by mistake you are passing x data instead of y as target data?

**So to fix the problem, you should pass correct y data, with shape (128, 128, 3), to the model.**

Comment: Thank you, my x and y had exact same shapes, I forgot to downscale one of them.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm happy that your problem is resolved :)